# How to set an htmlString to RichTextEditor

Tags: ios, ipad, nsattributedstring, rich-text-editor

I have a RichTextEditor and when I'm editing the text, it works perfectly. But when I try to just show the edited text, it shows something like this:

```
<p align="center" style=" "><i><font face="Baskerville"  style=" font-size:22px;
color:rgb(0,0,0); background-color:rgb(197,247,251); " >My text.</font></i></p>
```

I've tried to use this:

```
self.myRichTextEditor.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                       initWithString:htmlString];
```

(htmlString is the string above)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is RichTextEditor a third party lib? Are there any requirements in specifying contents?

Comment: Yes it's, but I found nothing about it in specifying contents. It looks like it's not prepared to do something like this, I mean, show a string already edited, just to make the edition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize attributed string with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` document type attribute. See [Document types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Document_Types) in documentation.

```
NSData *data = [@"<h1>hello</h1>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

self.label.attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithData:data
 options:attrs
 documentAttributes:nil
 error:nil];
```